# How to stop load the whole table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

The thing is, I have read right to one table,which is partition by year month and day.But I don't have right read the data from 2016/04/24.
when I execute in Hive command:

```
hive>select * from table where year="2016" and month="06" and day="01";
```

I CAN READ OTHER DAYS' DATA EXCEPT 2016/04/24

But,when I read in spark

```
sqlContext.sql.sql(select * from table where year="2016" and month="06" and day="01")
```

exceptition is throwable That I dont have the right to hdfs/.../2016/04/24

THIS SHOW SPARK SQL LOAD THE WHOLE TABLE ONCE AND THEN FILTER?
HOW CAN I AVOID LOAD THE WHOLE TABLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JdbcRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD)s directly. With it you can bypass spark sql engine therefore your queries will be directly sent to hive.

To use [`JdbcRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD) you need to create hive driver and register it first (of course it is not registered already).

```scala
val driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
Class.forName(driver)
```

Then you can create a [`JdbcRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD);

```scala
val connUrl = "jdbc:hive2://..."
val query = """select * from table where year="2016" and month="06" and day="01" and ? = ?"""
val lowerBound = 0
val upperBound = 0
val numOfPartitions = 1
new JdbcRDD(
    sc,
    () => DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl),
    query,
    lowerBound,
    upperBound,
    numOfPartitions,
    (r: ResultSet) => (r.getString(1) /** get data here or with a function**/)
)
```

[`JdbcRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD) query must have two `?` in order to create partition your data. So you should write a better query than me. This just creates one partition to demonstrate how it works.

However, before doing this I recommend you to check [`HiveContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.hive.package). This supports HiveQL as well. Check [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables).